# Getting enum value by getter not toString

Tags: android, enums, scope

I have one question about enums in Java. So I need to fill my Spinner Adapter with enum values. I know that i can override toString method inside enum and use values() but in this case I try to achieve that different way because I might need to leave toString() untouched.

I have make getters inside enums but I cant use them anywhere and I don't know why. It would be great if someone could point my error and directions to go further.

I want to populate my spinner with fist string value (`speciesLabel`) of my Enum.

When I try to call my getter in adapter, Android Studio says that there is not such method to call

```
speciesSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Species>(this,R.layout.row_default, Species.getSoeciesLabel()));
```

Species.java (Enum)

```
public enum Species {

    HUMAN("Human", "Human description", 90),
    GAND("Gand", "Gand description", 100);

    private final String speciesLabel;
    private final String speciesDescription;
    private final int startingXp;

    private Species(String speciesLabel, String speciesDescription, int startingXp) {
        this.speciesLabel = speciesLabel;
        this.speciesDescription = speciesDescription;
        this.startingXp = startingXp;
    }

    public String getSpeciesLabel() {
        return speciesLabel;
    }

    public String getSpeciesDescription() {
        return speciesDescription;
    }

    public int getStartingXp() {
        return startingXp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getSpeciesLabel();
    }

}
```

NewCharacterActivity.java

```
package com.example.androiddev_adam.starwarscharactercreator.views.activities;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.example.androiddev_adam.starwarscharactercreator.R;
import com.example.androiddev_adam.starwarscharactercreator.model.Species;

public class NewCharacterActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText toonName;
    private Spinner speciesSpinner;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ImageView speciesImage;
    private Button btnNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_character);

        toonName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.toonNameEditText);

        speciesSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.speciesSpinner);
        speciesSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Species>(this,R.layout.row_default, Species.values()));

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_character, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're unable to achieve. You're populating the spinner adapter with values... where do getters come in? Where does toString come in? Are you really just talking about how the values should be *displayed*? You say you can't use your getters anywhere - how are you trying to use them, and what goes wrong?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you need a subclass of `*Adapter`. `ArrayAdapter` calls internally `toString()`, to populate the spinner's views

Comment: I have tried to explain better what I want to achieve. Sorry for my language :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding ArrayAdapter constructor, The third parameter in the constructor is textViewResourceId to which set the Text! Suppose in `R.layout.row_default` you have a TextView named `txtTitle` that you want to set the `speciesLabel` in than do it like this:

```
speciesSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Species>(this,R.layout.row_default, R.id.txtTitle, Species.values()));
```

[Android Doc Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]))
From Reference:

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

Side Note:
Reason you are not able to call `Species.getSpeciesLabel()` is that `getSpeciesLabel()` is not a static method, so you cannot call it using class name. Following method calls are all valid:

```
// Get Label of a specific specie
Log.d("", Species.HUMAN.getSpeciesLabel());

// Get 
Species[] specieses = Species.values();
for (Species species : specieses) {
   Log.d("", species.getSpeciesLabel());
}
```

Comment: My row_default contains only TextView so I assume I don't need that third parameter.  I have made changes to my code `speciesSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Species>(this,R.layout.row_default,R.id.rowText, Species));` but Species is  now marked as red and compiler says Expression expected.

Comment: There was a mistake in my answer, you have to write instead Species.values()

Comment: So that basically means that I must make new Array and populate it by those labels and then call it in adapter? sounds like a big workaround :(

Comment: Not needed.. just passing Species.values() would be sufficient. which would in return create an array itself though!

Comment: But when I remove `@Override toString()` form my enum the result would be like `HUMAN` or `GAND` not `Human`, `Gand` (first String value of enum)

Comment: Yes that is true, default implementation of ArrayAdapter calls toString on Species object by default, to change this behaviour you would have to subclass ArrayAdapter and provide the implementation yourself!

Comment: Thanks! Now I know where to look